# Maximize Print Preview?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, system.printing

Is there any way to Maximize the Print Preview Dialogue?

I could not see any Maximize property on the controls at properties window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not available in the properties page because you have to cast the PrintPreviewDialog to a Form in order to access those Form properties:

```
DirectCast(PrintPreviewDialog1, Form).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Answer (score 5):

For C#:

```
(PrintPreviewDialog1 as Form).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```